# How to install and configure nodogsplash on TP-LINK MR3020 with Openwrt 12.09.02

Tags: configuration, installation, wifi, router, openwrt

I am trying to install and run the nodogsplash, I have installed it on my TP-LINK MR3020 Router but not able to configure it I follwed  [this link for installation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash)
and enabled nodogsplash service. but when I restart my router, my Wifi is not enabled and thus stuck, tried twice the same but no success.
can anyone help me with detail how to of running nodogsplash on MR3020.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had successful installing nodogsplash on TP-LINK MR3020 & TL-1043ND V2.1

For MR3020, the first thing is make sure your MR3020 is able to connect to internet, I'm follow [this link](http://www.ediy.com.my/index.php/blog/item/81-connect-two-wireless-router-wirelessly-bridge-using-tl-mr3020) to setup the internet connection.

Next is to install the nodogsplash, enter the following command into your SSH window:

- opkg update
- opkg install nodogsplash

starting http server

- /etc/init.d/uhttpd enable
- /etc/init.d/uhttpd start

Log in to Luci web interface to make sure the nodogsplash is started.

- Under System->Startup
- Look for nodogsplash
- It must show Enable under "Enable/Disable" column

Note:
I didn't make any changes to /etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf. However you may want to set the GatewayInterface to the interface on your router. For my case, I'm using the default value as shown below:

- GatewayInterface br-lan

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestion now I have installed the nodogsplash but not able redirect to nodogsplash page i only can get there after entering 192.168.1.1:2050, how to do it as a default redirection

Comment: Did you modify the /etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf file? What is your OpenWRT version? I'm using OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09 | Load: 0.37 0.18 0.07

Comment: No I didnt modified the nodagsplash.conf, what should be the possible modifications to achieve the redirection to custom splash page and allow the internet sites only if code entered by the user matches. my openWrt Attitude Adjustment is 12.09.2 | Load: 0.30 0.09 0.07

Comment: I wrote an article on how to setting up NoDogSplash on TL-MR3020, here is the link: http://www.ediy.com.my/index.php/blog/item/110-setting-up-a-wireless-hotspot-using-tp-link-tl-mr3020-wireless-n-router